# How to make a timer that starts with a long press on the button?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently learning Swift and iOS programming. I want to make a timer that starts with a long press on the button. At the same time I want to change the UIButton image. I leave button, I want the button revert back. Is this possible?

Comment: Friendly suggestion: don't ask if this is possible. Do it. *You will learn how to do it by actually doing it.* Then if you have an issue while doing it, an issue that you can't solve after reading documentation and debugging, then Stack Overflow is the right place to ask. If you just copy-paste code you will never learn.

Comment: You should first try to solve your problem by writing any code you think will do and then put it here for others to help make it work. If not possible, the least you can do is to describe it in more detail by supplementing it with some visual representation.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can do this. You have to add LongPressGestureRecognizer:

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(yourAction))
button.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

And then in your func start the timer and change the button's image:

```
func yourAction(){
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "yourImage"), for: .normal)
}


func timerAction(){
    //Do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will trying to the code but i don't know to the write "your action" title. And I add the button on the project. Is this wrong? @Phyber

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own solution for this, something along the lines

1- User touches down (UIControlEvent touchDown), you start a time that fires every x secs/millisecs

2- Timer will fire the action over and over

3- User touches up UICOntrolEvent touchUp, you cancel your timer

So you bind those 2 events to different functions, and start/kill your timers with appropriate actions

How that helps

I will add a code for demonstration:

```
@IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

var timer: Timer!
var speedAmmo = 100
@IBAction func buttonDown(sender: AnyObject) {
    singleFire()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector:#selector(rapidFire), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func buttonUp(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
}

func singleFire() {
    if speedAmmo > 0 {
        speedAmmo -= 1
        print("bang!")
    } else {
        print("out of speed ammo, dude!")
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}

func rapidFire() {
    if speedAmmo > 0 {
        speedAmmo -= 1
        print("bang!")
    } else {
        print("out of speed ammo, dude!")
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonDown(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonUp(sender:)), for: [.touchUpInside, .touchUpOutside])
}
```

Please try and let me know!

Comment: Yes maybe. But i don't know how to do it @Bashir Sidani

Comment: I Updated my answer for you :) just print the timer duration along the way!